# Spring Boot Application run failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

```
2019-07-12 17:32:57.619  WARN 24158 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/debug/DebugFilter

2019-07-12 17:32:57.639 ERROR 24158 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/debug/DebugFilter
```

What is this error? I can't find any sources to it.

Comment: If you check this line `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/security/web/debug/DebugFilter`, you will see that it cannot find this class in your project. Are you sure you have the jar spring-security-web in your classpath? Try this link to get the jar, use in maven or gradle : [ https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web/3.2.0.RELEASE ]. This should most probably resolve the issue.

Comment: Class missing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project is missing a dependency. Add below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Problem resolved. All spring-security dependency versions need to match. Why is this the case though? Thanks all.